# How do I get JSON data about website?

Tags: ios, json

This is a newbie question and may not have an answer. I want to visit a website on an iPhone/iPad and also gather and search all the information about the website. For example, If I search for a book and a page pops up I want to be able to read in the genres it falls under (Fiction, Fantasy, romance, Adventure, etc...) Any suggetions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you are developing the website, you can include a webservice which provides this data.  But to my knowledge there's no way to just retrieve all this data in any sort of concise format from just any random website without a webservice.

Comment: so you want to implement a website crawler? Sorry there is no magic wand, you have to code it yourself.

Comment: I think you may have the wrong idea about what JSON is. JSON is a format for sending data between server and client.

Comment: My apologies, sorry for the bad question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fetch website content(usually in HTML format) using ASIHTTPRequest or AFNetworking, then parse the HTML data, get the links of sub-pages. You may want to check [How to Parse HTML on iOS](http://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios).